# Disable keyboard backlight on MacBook Pro entirely on Windows

Tags: windows-10, macbook-pro, boot-camp

I'm on a MacBook Pro (probably '17 edition, can't be bothered to go to macOS to check) using Bootcamp to also use Windows (Windows 10).

Every single time I launch Windows -- or, rather, log in -- the keyboard backlight is enabled, and I have to manually turn it off using the keyboard (Fn + F5). And even if I turn it off, it somehow finds its way back on, which is incredibly annoying, and also terrible as it's clearly wasting power resources.

I am looking for some way to *turn keyboard backlight off **COMPLETELY***, so it will never see the light of day again.

This is my current Bootcamp keyboard settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

New for 2014:
You'd think you should be able to take care of this in one location but, no.

1. Open System Preferences, then open Keyboard, and in the first 'Keyboard' tab panel, uncheck "Adjust keyboard brightness in low light".  Also here, be sure to check the "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" checkbox so that your 'fn' key works.  Close the panel.
2. While holding down the <kbd>fn</kbd> key, press <kbd>F5</kbd>.  You should see a semi-transparent control with a setting sun icon.  Tap or hold until the bars go down to 0.

[Source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/122651/176218)

While it is unclear if this method will work within your multi boot setup, it is worth a try.

Comment: This doesn't help -- the settings are exactly the same as I mentioned in my post, and I also said that even if I disable it with Fn+F5, it chooses to enable itself again. It has its own life.

Comment: @gosr did you check out the second method in that link?